# Why should I not put all my data in one CosmosDB collection?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

**The problem**

I have [discovered](https://www.azurefromthetrenches.com/azure-cosmos-db-and-its-perplexing-pricing-problems/) that Cosmos DB is priced very aggressively and can be expensive if used with many data types.

I would think that a good structure, would be to put each data type I have in their own collection, almost like tables in a database (not quite).

However, each collection costs at least 24 USD per month. This is if I choose "Fixed", that limits me to 10GB and is NOT scalable. Hardly the point of Cosmos DB, so I would rather choose "Unlimited". However, here the price is at least 60 USD per month.

60 USD per month per data type.

This includes 1000 RU, but on top of this, I have to pay more for consumption.

This might be OK if I have a few data types, but if I a fully fledged business application with 30 data types (not at all uncommon), it becomes 1800 USD per month, at least. As a starting price. When I have no data yet.

**The question**

The structure of the data in the collection is not strict. I can store different types of documents in the same collection.

When using an "Unlimited" collection, I can use partition keys, which **should** be used to partition my data to ensure scalability.

**However, why do I not just include the data type in the partition key?**

Then the partition key becomes something like:

```
[customer-id]-[data-type]-[actual-partition-value, like 'state']
```

With one swift move, my minimum cost becomes 60 USD and the rest is based on consumption. Presumably, partition keys ensure satisfactory performance regardless of the data volume. So what am I missing? Is there some problem with this approach?

**Update**

Microsoft now supports sharing RU across all containers (without a minimum of 10000 RU) so this question is essentially no longer relevant, as you can now freely choose to separate data into different containers without any extra cost.

Comment: No there will be no problem per se. It all boils down to whether you're fine with having 1000 RU/s for your whole system. In fact you can simplify this even more by having your document id to be the partition key to enable the maximum distribution and scale in CosmosDB. That's exactly how [Collection sharing works in Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut#collection-sharing) and I have noticed no problems, even on systems with many different data types.

Comment: @NickChapsas your comment sounds more like an answer, so maybe post it as one?

Comment: @Haspemulator Oh sorry i wanted to write it as an answer but I clicked on the wrong area.

Comment: You can always start at fixed collection and migrate to unlimited collection once you're getting near the limits. Overprovisioning before you actually need it is to be expected to be expensive.

Comment: @ImrePühvel, although I know what you mean, here it is about more than only provisioning, because the Fixed does not support partition key and Unlimited does. So we would have to change quite fundamental things in the code when migrating to another collection type. With this question, I hope to avoid that.

Answer (score 3):

No there will be no problem per se. 
It all boils down to whether you're fine with having 1000 RU/s, or more specifically a single bottleneck, for your whole system.

In fact you can simplify this even more by having your document id to be the partition key. This will guarantee the uniqueness of the document id and will enable the maximum possible distribution and scale in CosmosDB.

That's exactly how [collection sharing works in Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut#collection-sharing) *(disclaimer, I'm the creator of this project)* and I have noticed no problems, even on systems with many different data types.

However you have to keep in mind that even though you can scale this collection up and down you still restrict your whole system with this one bottleneck. I would recommend that you don't just create one collection but probably 2 or 3 collections with shared entities in them. If this is done smart enough and you batch entities in a logical way then you can scale your throughput for specific parts of your system.

Comment: Is it really a bottleneck if we have different partitions? Let's say we have 10 documents in one partition. Is that faster than having 100 documents in 10 different partitions, if we just need the data from one partition?

Comment: The throughput is collection wide, not partition wide. It doesn't matter how many partitions you have. If you are constantly pumping and querying for data you might hit those 429s. Knowing the partition value only makes your queries faster and more cost efficient.

Comment: "your document id to be the partition key" - beware, this would cause a inefficient fan-out queries across all partitions should you ever need a select by other than id.

Comment: @ImrePühvel Which will be a problem anyway if he goes with the `[customer-id]-[data-type]-[actual-partition-value, like 'state']` approach.

Comment: Nick, throughput is OK, I will of course buy more RUs if I need more. Regarding the partition strategy that I propose, it would have thousands of documents in the same partition. As opposed to your proposed strategy where each document has their own partition. So it is not the same structure in terms of partitions.

Comment: That's why i recommended the `id` strategy. Because if you say that you are expecting to have thousands of documents per partition then you will probably meet the maximum of 10GB per partition, which you can do nothing about. You cannot lift it or change it and the only solution would be complete migration to a collection with a different key. Keep in mind Cosmos wont create a single partition per id but rather randomly distribute the documents in enough partitions to host them.

Comment: @NickChapsas I understand that, but I think Imres concern, which I agree with, is, that it would be inefficient to look up all closely related documents with your solution. I want to retain the possibility of grouping related documents together and look up on them efficiently, which I believe the proposal from my question accomplishes.